# No private directories found when I do have one?

Tags: filesystem, files, encryption

I have 2 hard drives that are both running Ubuntu 12.10.  One of the hard drives doesn't boot correctly but has the files I want to get from it. It also has an encrypted home directory and the bootable Ubuntu hard drive does not.

Now I tried to get inside of my non-bootable hard drive's home directory with the following command using my working Ubuntu machine I'm on right now:

```
user@User:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Hint: click 'Places' and select your hard disk, then run this again.
ERROR: No private directories found; make sure that your root filesystem is mounted.
```

But as you can see, it doesn't find it. I have the passphrase for the nonbootable hard drives encrypted home directory. So, what can I do to access the directory and copy those files to my working Ubuntu hard drive or the external one I have?

Comment: I am really y confused by your question. Please try to spend a bit more time by describing in details both machines, what you are trying to do on each and why do you want to call ecryptfs-recover-private.

Comment: @Huygens OK, I fixed it up to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mount the "other" drive before you can successfully run `ecryptfs-recover-private`.

I suggest the following steps:

1. `cd` to change into your homedirectory
2. `mkdir otherHDD`  to create a mountpoint for the other HDD
3. `mount` to see what is currently mounted
4. `blkid |grep ext`  to determine the name of the partition on the other HDD (probably something like `/dev/sdb2`). You will see several entries, choose a "likely" one, you won't damage here anything.
5. `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 otherHDD` (or whatever looked likely in  the step above)
6. `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`
7. If you get an empty result: `sudo umount otherHDD`, then back to *step 5* with another partition selected.

Just for completeness:
The  *LOGIN Passphrase* you will be asked about is either

- your regular login password in the "other" system 
  or
- it might be the "passphrase" that was generated when you encrypted your homedir and which you hopefully stored in a secure place.